# How to get download progress in the Google Drive API (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

I use this function to download file from the Google Drive API and I want to get download progress. Maybe anybody knows how to do it?

```
func download(file: GTLRDrive_File) {
    let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/\(file.identifier!)?alt=media"
    let fetcher = drive.fetcherService.fetcher(withURLString: url)
    fetcher.beginFetch(completionHandler: { data, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        //Here I save data to the Documents
    })
}
```

I tried to get it from `fetcher.receivedProgressBlock` but it's always return nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution. Actual for Swift 5:

```
func download(file: GTLRDrive_File) {
    let fileSize = file.size?.doubleValue //You need to fetch file size in your request q.fields = "kind,nextPageToken,files(mimeType,id,name,size)"
    let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/\(file.identifier!)?alt=media"
    let fetcher = drive.fetcherService.fetcher(withURLString: url)
    fetcher.beginFetch(completionHandler: { data, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        //Here I save data to the Documents
    })

    //Here you can get total bytes received (value is updated in real time)
    fetcher.receivedProgressBlock = { _, totalBytesReceived in
            guard let fileSize = fileSize else { return }
            let progress = Double(totalBytesReceived) / fileSize
            print(progress) //Here you can update UI (progress bar) or do something else
        }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. file.size?.doubleValue return nil

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `file.size` returns nil so I used `fetcher.response?.expectedContentLength` instead.

```
func download(file: GTLRDrive_File, service: GTLRDriveService) {

    let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/\(file.identifier!)?alt=media"
    let fetcher = service.fetcherService.fetcher(withURLString: url)
    fetcher.beginFetch(completionHandler: { fileData, error in
        
        if error == nil {
            
            print("finished downloading file Data...")
            print(fileData as Any)
            // do anything with data here
        
        } else {
            
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
    
    
    fetcher.receivedProgressBlock = { _, totalBytesReceived in
        print("totalBytesReceived: \(totalBytesReceived)")
        print("size: \(fetcher.response?.expectedContentLength)")
        
        if let fileSize = fetcher.response?.expectedContentLength {
            
            let progress: Double = Double(totalBytesReceived) / Double(fileSize)
            print(progress)
            // Update progress bar here
        }
    }

}
```